# Why is ChromeDriver working in Debug mode but not on release?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-chromedriver

So I have this **c# console app** that I'm creating.

It uses Selenium ChromeDriver to create WordPress menus.
It's working perfectly on debug mode.

Now I release it and when I install the app, run it, it's giving me this error:

> The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current t directory or
>   in a directory on the PATH environment variable.

This is where I believe I'm getting this error:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I've searched all over the internet but nothing seems to work, I think it's something that has to do with Publishing in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is `chromedriver.exe` included in your project?

Comment: Yes, in the bin folder. I corrected my post, the problem I'm having should be clear now @haim770

Comment: You mean that it's getting copied to your `bin` folder? What is the `Build Action` of the file?

Comment: I fixed up my question description, the problem I'm having should be clear now. @haim770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you have installed the NuGet package `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver`. You will find the latest chrome driver in `\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver\driver\win32\chromedriver.exe` select the correct version based on system.

Add the file to your project, then in the file properties select under "Copy to Output Directory" either "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer".

**This question should help**

[Selenium WebDriver.ChromeDriver Nuget package installed, but not working for MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695742/selenium-webdriver-chromedriver-nuget-package-installed-but-not-working-for-mst)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, the program is working now!

Comment: @KhalilPierre Happy to help, Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Copy chromedriver.exe from your Debug folder to your Release folder.

Comment: Sounds like a nice one, I'll try it.

Comment: Riddell's answer should also work. It comes down to the same thing - Release runs from a different folder, and chromedriver.exe needs to be in that folder.

Comment: I don't know much about the release, but I'm glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

From the project owner [github](https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/) page:

"chromedriver(.exe) isn't included in published files on default configuration. This behavior is by design."

If you want to include "chromedriver(.exe)" into published files, please define "_PUBLISH_CHROMEDRIVER" compilation symbol (Under Project > Properties > Build)

[image]